# Selecting a dropdown value based on JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to build a simple jquery plugin that queries a geolocation system and returns data about where the users IP is based, preselecting it in an HTML form.

I have an HTML select with all the country codes in as values. I need to select the one referenced in the returned data. This is what I have so far...

```
(function($){

    $.fn.geoselect = function() {

        $.getJSON('http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?jsoncallback=?', function(data) {
            this.attr("selected", "selected");
        });

    };

})(jQuery);
```

Obviously this wont work currently as 'this' related to the select as a whole, not one of its options. If the data returned is 'GB' for example, I need to select the option with a value of 'GB'.

Comment: Can you post an example of your json object, to figure out the structure?

Comment: That URL is actually a live service so you should see a real example. Out of that data its the "geoplugin_countryCode" value, eg: "GB"

Comment: http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?jsoncallback=?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're inside **$.getJSON**, so `this` isn't going to refer to your select. Instead, save it to a variable in the parent scope and then access it in the callback. You can then use the `.find()` method to get the specific `<option>` tag.

I'm also going to assume that the data you're getting back from the API is `data['geoplugin_city']`

```
$.fn.geoselect = function() {
    var dropdown = this;

    $.getJSON('http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?jsoncallback=?', function(data) {
        $(dropdown).find('option[value="' + data['geoplugin_city'] + '"]').attr("selected", "selected");
    });
};
```

Comment: Well spotted! Nice one Jamie :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `this.attr("selected", "selected");` do this:

```
var selectedData = 'GB' // assuming you extracted it from JSON data already

$("option[value='" + selectedData + "']", $(this)).attr("selected", "selected"); // Assuming that "this" is a reference to your picklist.
```

Comment: Hmm, no errors but it doesn't seem to be working... I setup an example on jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/sru59/

Comment: @Plasticated. I checked your jsfiddle. The reason it isn't selected is because the value attribute of each option element in the select are lowercase. Just do this: $("option[value='" + data.geoplugin_countryCode.toLowerCase() + "']", $(this)).attr("selected", "selected");